# PostMan vs Axios on Including authorization Header while Making requests

Tags: reactjs, axios, postman

Making a postman request to an endpoint with some Header

[image]

when I run the below code

```
  function authenticateToken(req,res,next){

    const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"]
    console.log(req.headers)
    if(typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined'){
        const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
        const bearerToken = bearer[1];
        req.token = bearerToken;
        next();
    }
    else{
        console.log('hihihi')
        res.sendStatus(403);
    }

}//a middleware function used for JWT
```

it's returning everything as I expected like below

[image]

but the problem is, I need to connect it with my react. So I am making Axios request but it's not working
I tried giving headers using interceptors like below

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
            config=>{
                config.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
                return config
            },
            error =>{
                return Promise.reject(error)
                return error
            }
        )
        axios.post("http://localhost:3000/stockdata/post",{
                // some data
})
```

I also tried giving like below

```
 axios.post(url,{data},{headers:{
                      'authorization': "Bearer "+ token,
                      'Accept': 'application/json',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                })
```

i also tried with **'Authorization': "Bearer "+ token** and without quotes **Authorization: "Bearer "+token** and also tried one time by removing **Accept** and **content-type** . but this is what am getting

[image]

The problem is only with the Axios request, not any other thing. what's going wrong in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you tried with axios, there will be two requests as it has CORS issue. This issue comes if the client host is different from server host.
The first request is type OPTIONS to know whether to allow the POST or not and second request is actual POST.

What you are seeing might be of request type OPTIONS. This you can verify by checking network tab in the browser. This won't happen in POSTMAN. You could add CORS plugin to your server to resolve this issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you. I thought the error was somewhere in sending the token from react but its actually a cors problem.

Answer (score 0):

The attached screenshot shows POSTMAN sending request to http://localhost:3000/stockdata/post

However, the axios request is being sent to http://localhost:3000/stockdata

Adjusting the request end-point may help resolve the issue.

After adjusting the target URL, the following code example may be tried to get the axios response:

```
import axios from 'axios'

let url = "http://localhost:3000/stockdata/post"
let data = {}
let token = "xyz"
let config = {"headers": {
                   "Authorization": "Bearer " + token, 
                   "content-type": "application/json"
                }
             }


axios.post(url, data, config)
     .then((response) => {
               console.log(response)
          }, (error) => {
               console.log(error)
          }
     )
```

**More information:**

https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-http-requests-like-a-pro-with-axios/